# How to modify the Address info class file

Tags: kentico

In kentico 10 how to modify the Address info class meta file. I checked to the dev. documets in kentico

Comment: stackoverflow is not meant to be a code writing service. You should try something on your own and when the code is not working ask a question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also please check out the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section

Answer (score 1):

Take a [look at the Kentico Documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/customizing-the-system-s-data-classes-info-objects).  Also if you don't need a strongly typed class, you can simply access the field/column data like so:

```
// get info
AddressInfo address = AddressInfoProvider.GetAddressInfo(123);
string customValue = address.GetStringValue("YourColumnName", "");

// update info
AddressInfo address = AddressInfoProvider.GetAddressInfo(123);
address.SetValue("CustomColumn", "your value");
AddressInfoProvider.SetAddressInfo(address);
```

Also, check out the [Kentico API Examples](https://docs.kentico.com/api10/e-commerce) for more information.